# Is there anything like BOXLAYOUT in SWT Eclipse

Tags: layout, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I need to arrange Component One below other like Swing's BoxLayout Y axis scenario .
I thought of using Gridlayout inside Gridlayout , but is there any better option. I have already 4 columns and inside each Column I need to add different elements Y-axis based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Use `RowLayout`. You will find more on this [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html). If you don't want wrapping of your controls (behavior of Swing's BoxLayout) then you could use `FillLayout` as it lays out equal-sized widgets in a single row or column.